# Production push notification steps

Tags: iphone, ios4, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

im trying to developing an iphone app with push notification, every thing going well when i use the **Development Push SSL Certificate** and i received the push correctly,

**BUT** now i have **no idea about Production Push SSL Certificate** 
How can i develop an app use **Production Push SSL Certificate** to use it for ad-Hoc ??

any idea :)

Comment: are you using urbanairship? or something else?

Comment: @Saurabh what is urbanairship??
i did not see any thing like this in apple portal 
do i need any thing out of apple portal??

Comment: with http://urbanairship.com/ you can easily integrate push notification in your app... try using it!

Comment: @Saurabh i would to ask you,, if i must use urbanairship ?!!
OR i can send push without any help like urbanairship ??

Comment: no there is no need to use urbanairship to send push notifications.. but it makes it very much easy to integrate push notifications in app. if you are using default way then you just need to export the production certificate and send this certificate to apple server..